# spring jdbc and composite primary keys

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Is there a way in spring jdbc to return a composite primary key when a row is inserted.
This composite primary key is made up of values from separate sequences

Any help is greatly appreciated

Regards
Damien

Comment: I would like some clarification on "Spring JDBC"; do you mean with Hibernate mappings or some other JPA framework? I am not aware of any build in JDBC functionality that Spring offers.

One other note: It is often a good idea to use ONE generated primary key column when your table's records are uniquely identified by a composite key. Especially if that composite key is just multiple generated columns. I would review your DB design to see if simplifying things will make using these frameworks easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a full example (tested on PostgreSQL 8.4):

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  otherid serial NOT NULL,
  val text,
  CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, otherid)
)
```

This is how you get keys back:

```
public void doStuff() {
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    jdbcTemplate.update(
            new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into test(val) values (?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                    ps.setInt(1, 42);
                    return ps;
                }
            },
            keyHolder);

    keyHolder.getKeys().get("id");
    keyHolder.getKeys().get("otherid");
}
```

Now, if you want to get your composite key as an instance of some class directly from keyHolder, it is not simple.

JdbcTemplate uses ColumnMapRowMapper to map generated keys (generated keys are returned as result set, at least on PostgreSQL. It actually returns the whole row as if you were executing select on the row you just inserted). Same ColumnMapRowMapper is used in number of other places in JdbcTemplate.

The only possible point of extension here is KeyHolder itself. Here is what you can do:

```
public void doStuff() {
    CompositeKeyHolder keyHolder = new CompositeKeyHolder();
    ... same code here ...

    keyHolder.getCompositeKey();
}


class CompositeKeyHolder extends GeneratedKeyHolder {
    private boolean converted;

    public CompositeKey getCompositeKey() {
        return new CompositeKey((Integer)this.getKeys().get("id"), (Integer)this.getKeys().get("otherid"));
    }
}


class CompositeKey {

    private Integer id;

    private Integer otherId;

    CompositeKey(Integer id, Integer otherId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.otherId = otherId;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Integer getOtherId() {
        return otherId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic idea for a single key. The long id at the end is the key. If you have multiple sequences, I would recommend just using two separate statements to get each generated key.

```
JdbcTemplate template = getJdbcTemplate();
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
template.update(
    new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(...);
            return ps;
        }
    },
    keyHolder);
long id = keyHolder.getKey().longValue();
```

Comment: Single keys are the easy case, and don't really need explanation. Composite keys are the question, and appear to have no easy/efficient solution.

Comment: That is true, but I wasn't sure if Damien knew the easy answer. The other part is that if you are inserting data into a table using 2 generated keys in one statement, it sounds like a potential design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

What database server are you using? MySQL only allows one auto_increment field per table and I'd imagine this is often the case, but without knowing your setup it's hard to say. Assuming there is only one auto_generated field in your table, your INSERT would have had to be aware of the value going into the second PK field. Robert's code should work for retrieving the generated key value, and the cleanest solution would probably be to perform a SELECT after the fact using this generated key and the value which you had a hold of already.

Comment: MySQL is not a good guide to other databases - it's crude and primitive. Composite keys are well supported by proper databases, but Spring JDBC doesn't seem to have good support for this concept.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is [GeneratedKeyHolder.getKeys()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/GeneratedKeyHolder.html#getKeys%28%29). Code would look like [this example](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-auto-genereted-keys), except you will have to call

```
keyHolder.getKeys()
```

instead of

```
keyHolder.getKey()
```